# Automatic Input Method Change on Samsung Galaxy Tab

Tags: keyboard, samsung-galaxy-tab, swype

The tab frequently attempts to change input method from Swype to keyboard dock. I don't own a keyboard dock. How do I stop this? Can't find it in the Settings.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked in `Settings -> Language and keyboard`? Deselecting it from here should help.